# Working with multiple values and metaboxes

Tags: custom-field, metabox, array

I have multiple values I need to be able to punch into a meta-box on the post edit screen.

EX: I am working with set-list information for concerts.

1. Song 1
2. Song 2
3. Song 3

etc...

I am always looking for efficiency in my code, here's the point:

Do I just create a brand new id (i.e. song_1, song_2) for every song. Or is there a more condensed way to go about this. Here's a sample of how I would do it as of right now... which would seem like a lot of unncessary code, but then again I am not certain.

```
<?php   
include('preset-library.php');

$meta_box['post'] = array(

// default values, will change to more descriptive values later

    'id' => 'post-format-meta',  
    'title' => 'Additional Post Format Meta',    
    'context' => 'normal',           
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Song 1',
            'desc' => 'Setlist Song 1',
            'id' => 'song_1',
            'type' => 'text',
            'default' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Song 2',
            'desc' => 'Setlist Song 2',
            'id' => 'song_2',
            'type' => 'text',
            'default' => ''

// then additional songs 

        )
    )
);
add_action('admin_menu', 'plib_add_box');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your best option would be to create a single field and save all values in an array, something like this: [**Create more Meta Boxes as needed**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/create-more-meta-boxes-as-needed/19852#19852).

Answer (score 0):

You could look at adding a custom select meta box for the songs instead of just having multiple text boxes.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

You can then code it up to be a select box with each option in.