# How do I create a Meta box that can be repeated? (with an image section and text area)

Tags: metabox, custom-write-panel

What I need to do is have a meta box that you can select an Image (via the built in media uploader), and then add a caption to it using a text box with the TinyMCE bar - and once this is done, another one can then be added below if needed.

I found a similar question, with an answer, here: [Create more Meta Boxes as needed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/create-more-meta-boxes-as-needed) but I am not sure how to adapt it to my needs.

I know this kind of functionality is possible with Advanced Custom Fields, but I would prefer to be able to learn to build this functionality myself.

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've accomplished this using the [WPAlchemy](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) library.

Might not meet completely your "do it myself" requirement, but the functionality is there and you can tweak it to accomplish a lot without having to code everything from scratch.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! :) does exactly what I want, and still has a bit of coding to do so I don't feel too lazy (as apposed to just installing any old Custom Field plugin)