# How to display meta box data using "Meta boxes as needed"

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I have been following this post exactly: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19852/14957 and have everything working in the backend but when I try to use `echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'songs', true);` in my template all that is shown is `Array`. Any ideas? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wish to try;

```
<?php

  $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('my_key');
  foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
    echo "$key  => $value ('my_key')<br />"; 
  }

?>
```

Where my_key would be equal to songs.

Another example of what I might do in a situation where I am dealing with multiple values;

```
<?php

  global $post;
  $meta = get_post_custom_values($post->ID, 'songs', true );

   foreach ( $meta as $value ) {
      echo $value . "<br />"; 
    }

?>
```

Update: Try the following instead, which will cycle through each title and track of your 'songs' post meta.

```
global $post;
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'songs', true );
  foreach ( $meta as $key => $value ) {
      echo $value['title'] . "<br />";
       echo $value['track'] . "<br />";
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I tried your first example and seemed to get further than the second. Now, instead of just showing Array, it shows

0 => a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:13:"Song Name";s:5:"track";s:1:"1";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:18:"Song Name";s:5:"track";s:1:"2";}i:2;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:4:"Song Name";s:5:"track";s:1:"3";}i:3;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:13:"Song Name";s:5:"track";s:1:"4";}i:4;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:30:"Song Name";s:5:"track";s:1:"5";}} ('songs')

So it is showing what I have filled out in the backend just  mashed up in that.

Comment: The second example showed nothing.

Comment: @prochevnik Please try the following, this will give you the title and the track from 'songs'.

`global $post;
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'songs', true );
  foreach ( $meta as $key => $value ) {
      echo $value['title'] . "<br />";
       echo $value['track'] . "<br />";
    }` - added code above for clarity.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help. That worked perfectly.