# How to Create Dynamic Fields in a Meta Box?

Tags: custom-field, metabox

Could someone explain me with a little example how create a button that creates a new custom field dynamically?

I'm working on a plugin and using `add_meta_box`, I need an input box (administration-side) and a button that when clicked will create a new input box, after saving the previous data (on a custom database).

Comment: Are you looking for something like this - http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/2/1/

You want to add many values under one custom field just like that example ?

Comment: yes! Exactly! Could you help me with a simple example of this in case of a form in a post-new.php ? How do this with a plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for *Repeatable Fields*.

Here in WPSE, it was covered in the following **Q&A**:
[Custom Meta Boxes: Store two values in one repeatable field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/52383/12615)

A **Gist**:
https://gist.github.com/2057532

**Class helpers** for building the plugin options page:

- [Option Panel Class](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/my-options-panel) <sup>(from Bainternet, one of the house moderators)</sup>
- [WPAlchemy_MetaBox PHP class](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/)