# Metabox with multiple fields added by user and upload box

Tags: custom-field, images, metabox, uploads

I'm trying to build system, where user can add as many fields as he needs to the post. I'm using code from [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/create-more-meta-boxes-as-needed) thread. Everythings works fine, except I can't get my upload working.

Here's code I've added inside foreach loop in `dynamic_inner_custom_box()` function:

```
<input class="upload_file" type="text" size="45" id="items[%1$s][picture]" name="items[%1$s][picture]" value="%6$s" />
<input class="upload_button button" type="button" value="Upload File" />
<input class="upload_file_id" type="hidden" id="items[%1$s][picture]_id" name="items[%1$s][picture]_id" value="%6$s" />
```

The `%6$s` value is `item['picture']` ofc. I don't understand how this works. There are two fields for upload - `.upload_file` and `.upload_file_id`. If I'm correct, I need to add `_id` to my `.upload_file`'s name, and save it as `.upload_file_id`'s name. The problem is, when I choose some image from the upload thickbox, it doesn't put the link in my input field. I've been playing for a while now, and I've been able to get this link in place by playing with names/id's but than I couldn't save the data. What's incorrect in my code? Do I need to extend somehow save function?

@edit
After changing code to this:

```
<input class="upload_file" type="text" size="45" id="picture_%1$s" name="picture_%1$s" value="%6$s" />
<input class="upload_button button" type="button" value="Upload File" />
<input class="upload_file_id" type="hidden" id="picture_%1$s_id" name="items[%1$s][picture]" value="%6$s" />
```

I am finally saving something and I'm able to get attachment link in right place for a moment. When I coose a picture, a link is inserted where it should be, but after saving only some numbers are stored in databse ( attachment ID maybe? ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I've done it. No changes to the save function are needed. I've been trying to save data from both fields at once, thats why it didn't worked.

```
<input class="upload_file" type="text" size="45" id="picture_%1$s" name="picture_%1$s" value="%6$s" />
<input class="upload_button button" type="button" value="Upload File" />
<input class="upload_file_id" type="hidden" id="picture_%1$s_id" name="items[%1$s][picture]" value="%7$s" />
```

The value stored in `.upload_file_id` is attachment ID (`%7$s` == `item['picture']`).
The value displayed in `.upload_file` (`%6$s`) is `wp_get_attachment_image_src` like so:

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($item['picture']);
$img = $img[0];
```

And then we set `%6$s` to be `$img`. So in database just the attachment ID is stored, and we display link using WordPress function.