# I need help in designing a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I've been sitting on this for three days and I still haven't figured out a good way to solve this problem—that's why i want to ask a community about it.

I'm creating a page, which will have some historical routes in my city. I therefor need to create a custom post-type, which will be the route.

Route have points. Each point store multiple data: name, content, GPS-coordinates, author, etc.

So I need to create a repeatable area called `point` and there I'll insert all the data I need (amount of points is dynamic so this area need to be repeatable).

I've done that with help from this question: [Create more Meta Boxes as needed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/create-more-meta-boxes-as-needed)

It works fine, but there's a problem because the content-field needs to be the TinyMCE-editor and for now I'm stuck on the part where i add a repeatable area through jQuery, because I can't add TinyMCE to it in a easy way.

Is this a good plan or should I try another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Points have such a complex structure then shouldn't you think of it as another custom post type, and associate them to a Route (or to several Routes)? that way you could have a Point in different Routes, which could be a reasonable expectation.

Comment: Thats a good idea. I will reconsider changing to this becouse atm i used WPAlchemy class to setup repeatable fields including WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

That could be easily achieved with Advanced Custom Fields attached to a simple custom post type of yours using the [Repeater field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/) which can contain infinite sets of field of any type. ( WYSIWYG included. )

I can understand how a solution using default meta-boxes would be more desired but Advanced Custom Fields provides a great/simple UI for the back-end and unlimited possibilities for the front-end.