# dynamically add a custom field or metabox to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create more Meta Boxes as needed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/create-more-meta-boxes-as-needed)

I am creating a plugin that registers a Custom Post Type. Let's call it "Cars". I am looking to be able to add custom fields(or metaboxes) when I am editing a car, just like what you can do now with a custom field in a post or a CPT but I want to be able to control the HTML/CSS for it(for example I would like it to have 3 input fields).
So for example when you are editing a car, there would be a "add new field" button and when you press it a new custom field/metabox(with predefined structure and styling by me) would be added.

Let me know if I am not clear. Thank you!

Comment: This seems to answer the question
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/create-more-meta-boxes-as-needed

Comment: [blog](http://blog.drinkncode.com/add-fields-dynamically-in-custom-content-type-in-wordpress/) explaining how to achieve this, hope this helps someone..

Answer (score 1):

To add a metabox to a post type `car` use the proper hook:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_car', 'register_car_metabox' );

function register_car_metabox()
{

    add_meta_box(
        'car-data',
        'Car data',
        'car_metabox_callback',
        NULL,
        'normal',
        'default'
    );
}
```

The content will be created in your callback:

```
function car_metabox_callback()
{
    # get post meta and print input fields
}
```

Comment: Thanks Toscho. Not quite what I was looking for though :)