# How to write an efficient metabox with repetitive fields

Tags: metabox, array, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create more Meta Boxes as needed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/create-more-meta-boxes-as-needed)

I’m having a hard time to write an efficient code for the below Metabox. Since I **do not** want to use any third-party class, I’m trying to do it by myself, but so far no luck.

[image]

Could you show me an efficient way to create the Metabox as above? Number of sets and fields could be 3 or 10, so it should be flexible.