# Can I dynamically create duplicate fields with the Settings API?

Tags: settings-api

I'm not sure that my title accurately explains what I'm trying to do, but it's the best way I could think of to explain what I'm attempting to do.

I'm writing my first Wordpress plugin, and while it's been a huge learning experience so far, I've found myself stuck.

Basically, the plugin adds a shortcode, `[routes_and_schedules_accordion]` that generates a jQuery accordion that's a more fleshed-out version of this:

```
<ul class="accordion">
  <li class="panel">
    <div class="title">
      <h5>Route 1 - Market Street</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="http://www.example.com/Route1.pdf">Current Schedule</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

After a **lot** of reading, I've created an options page with the Settings API that lets me change the name of the route and the URL to its schedule (we're a small bus agency):

```
<?php $options = get_option('routes_and_schedules_accordion_settings') ?>

<ul class="accordion">
  <li class="panel">
    <div class="title">
      <h5><?php echo $options['route_name'] ?></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="<?php echo $options['route_current_schedule_url'] ?>">Current Schedule</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I'm really struggling with is making it so that new routes can be added. The goal is for the options page to have a way of adding and removing routes, and for the shortcode to spit out something like this:

```
<?php $options = get_option('routes_and_schedules_accordion_settings') ?>

<ul class="accordion">
  <li class="panel">
    <div class="title">
      <h5><?php echo $options['route1_name'] ?></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="<?php echo $options['route1_current_schedule_url'] ?>">Current Schedule</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="panel">
    <div class="title">
      <h5><?php echo $options['route2_name'] ?></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="<?php echo $options['route2_current_schedule_url'] ?>">Current Schedule</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I guess I could just make new fields each time the number of routes changes and update the plugin every single time, but that would be a lot of work, and I know that there has to be better way.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Are you looking for repeatable fields? Examples: [WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19852/12615) and  [Gist](https://gist.github.com/1593065).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this with options, save the routes as an array rather than individual options, or save the number of routes in an option so you can dynamically create and fetch them by building the option names based on the number you save.

**However**, rather than saving this stuff in options, I would make a route [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types). Route data would be post meta data, schedules would be an attachment, and you could use custom taxonomies to further group/filter routes.

Comment: +1. Options should be *discrete*. If a content type is intended to consist of an arbitrary number of "units" of that content, then it would be better served as a custom *post* type.

Comment: @ChipBennett If I were to make a `route` custom post type, how would I go about putting the data from all of them into a single page as an accordion? Would I be able to make a shortcode that did it? I'm considering the "save the number of routes in an option" idea, and I think I like it the most. How would I implement that?

Comment: @DrewBuglione you could use either **`archive-route.php`** that WordPress would use to output the archive index page for the `route` post-type, or else create a **custom page template** on which you would output your own custom query loop.