# Using a loop to build and update widgets

Tags: php, widgets

So I have a widget Im making which allows users to update 4 switches. Each switch has the same fields, name, description, price, amount so I decided to build the widget using a for loop instead of hard coding each field to avoid repeating myself.

I cant figure out how to save the values tho, because from teh tuts I've looked at for building widgets, the name field has to be $this->get_field_name which produces something like

widget-switches-widget[4][name]

So my form() function looks like

```
for($i =0; $i<4;$i++){
    $name = $instance[$i]['name'];  
    $description = $instance[$i]['description'];    
    $amount = $instance[$i]['amount'];  
    $price = $instance[$i]['price'];
?>

    <div id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="switch_form" style="background-color:<?php echo $i%2 == 0 ? '': '#DFDFDF' ;?>; border-radius:4px; padding:5px;">
        <h4>Switch # <?php echo $i+1;?> </h4>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>"><?php _e('Name:', 'Name'); ?></label>
            <input style ="width:90%;" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name($i); ?>['name']" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'description' ); ?>"><?php _e('Description:', 'Description'); ?></label>
            <input style ="width:90%;" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name($i); ?>['description']" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'amount' ); ?>"><?php _e('Amount:', 'Amount'); ?></label>
            <input style ="width:90%;" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name($i); ?>['amount']" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'price' ); ?>"><?php _e('Price:', 'Price'); ?></label>
            <input style ="width:90%;" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name($i); ?>['price']" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" />
        </p>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

and my update() function looks like:

```
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance )
{
    $instance = $old_instance;

    for($i =0; $i<4;$i++){
        $instance[$i]['name'] = strip_tags( $new_instance[$i]['name'] );
        $instance[$i]['description'] = strip_tags( $new_instance[$i]['description'] );      
        $instance[$i]['amount'] = strip_tags( $new_instance[$i]['lights_fill'] );
        $instance[$i]['price'] = strip_tags( $new_instance[$i]['price'] );
    }
    return $instance;

}
```

How would I save these values into an array?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I followed your code correctly, but you could try to set all data into *one* array:

```
name="unique_widget_name[<?php echo $this->get_field_name($i); ?>]['name']"
```

Very similar question, but not identical: [How to store widget fields data as an array?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94617/how-to-store-widget-fields-data-as-an-array)

Comment: isnt that redundant? $this->get_field() is already an array, im passing $i in to build nested arrays for the fields.

Basically, im trying to build and save 4 forms, each with teh same fields, in a single widget.

Comment: You get just one array to check now: `unique_widget_name`. I think this is what you want to parse. But maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: right, so i already have a unique array name, so all teh fields look like: `widget-switches-widget[4][0][name]`, and `widget-switches-widget[4][0][price]`and `widget-switches-widget[4][1][name]` but they aren't saving

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Have the same issue.