# Formatting of curly brackets array from WP database to get more readable output

Tags: plugin-development, database, array

E.g. when I want to edit something in my WP database, I get a headache, literally. Because I see something like this:

```
 a:92:{s:47:"category/(.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$";s:52:"index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]";s:42:"category/(.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$";s:52:"index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]";s:35:"category/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$";s:53:"index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]";s:17:"category/(.+?)/?$";s:35:"index.php?category_name=$matches[1]";s:44:"tag/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$";s:42:"index.php?ta-9]{1,})/?$";s:50:"index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]";}
```

I guess it's some kind of array, but my text editor cannot format that to something like this:

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
```

how can this be done with the stored data in PW database? Is there some online tool for that or maybe some plugin for Sublime Text 2 or N++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [serialized value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), so you should run it through `maybe_unserialize()` or just `unserialize()` before you edit it.

When you work in plugins or themes, always use the API: `update_option()` and `get_option()` for example. These functions will un/serialize the values for you, so you don’t have to worry about the database.

See also:

- [Settings API with arrays example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100023/settings-api-with-arrays-example)
- [How to store widget fields data as an array?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94617/how-to-store-widget-fields-data-as-an-array)
- [How do I retrieve multi-dimensional arrays from the wp_postmeta table, & display on a website?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95336/how-do-i-retrieve-multi-dimensional-arrays-from-the-wp-postmeta-table-display)
- [WordPress serializes options and meta for you](http://nacin.com/2010/04/18/wordpress-serializing-data/).

If you need just a simple converter, use WordPress’ internals: a simple dashboard widget and the built-in functions.

[image]

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: Unserialize Dashboard Widget */

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 't5_unserialize_dashboard_widget' );

function t5_unserialize_dashboard_widget()
{
    $handle = 't5sdw';

    add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', function() use ( $handle ) {

        wp_add_dashboard_widget(
            $handle . '_widget',
            'Unserialize',
            function() use ( $handle ) {

                print '<form action="' . admin_url( 'admin-post.php?action=' . $handle ) . '" method="post">';
                wp_nonce_field( 'update', $handle . '_nonce' );
                $content = esc_textarea( var_export( maybe_unserialize( get_option( $handle ) ), TRUE ) );

                print "<textarea name='$handle' class='code large-text' rows=10>$content</textarea><p>";
                submit_button( 'Unserialize', 'primary', $handle . '_unserialize', FALSE );
                print '</p></form>';
            }
        );
    });

    add_action( "admin_post_$handle", function() use ( $handle ) {

        if ( ! isset ( $_POST[ $handle ] )
            or ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $handle . '_nonce' ], 'update' ) )
            return;

        parse_str( file_get_contents( 'php://input', 'r'), $arr );
        update_option( $handle, $arr[ $handle ] );
        wp_redirect( admin_url( '/' ) );
        exit;
    });
}
```

Comment: but, can you tell me how the WP developers check these values in the db via some db client or phpmyadmin, just to check the actions etc. during development. It's very inconvinient this way as it is stored in the database. E.g. I run some function and then check the result in the db. if something was edited or changed as it supposed to be. But if I see the "serialized value" I am completely lost with verifing. Any idea how to solve this issue when developing plugins for wordpress?

Comment: @Derfder See my update.

Comment: Yeah, htanks , however I would still prefer to make fast corrections and changes via the database editor like Heidi or even phpmyadmin e.g. for unsetting cron for plugins etc. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Derfder Since you have asked for a tool, I have written a simple dashboard widget. It should show how these things work.

Comment: Wow, the plugin is really neat, but maybe I will add another button Serialize, that will appear after you make it unserialize. That way you can make some edits in it after unserializing and if you are finished serialize it back with the new info and then copy and paste to the db field.

Comment: @Derfder The problem with that is: you have to `eval()` the POSTed string to do that, and that is … dangerous.

Comment: What about doing it via javascript without using php at all?

Comment: @Derfder Hm, good idea. See PHP.js: [`serialize()`](http://phpjs.org/functions/serialize/) and [`unserialize()`](http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize/).