# How to add/save/retrieve additional fields to all available widgets?

Tags: widgets

I cant seem to find any complete tutorial that shows how to add / save/ retrieve a fields to any widget. Can someone please show a simple example how to add a simple select , save the data and retrieve it in front.

All I got so far is this   http://prntscr.com/76d051

```
add_action('in_widget_form', 'add_widget_fields');
function add_widget_fields(){


    $html ='<select class="custom_widget_select" name="dont know">';
    $html .='<option value="blue">Blue</option>';
    $html .='<option value="red">Red</option>';
    $html .='<option value="green">Green</option>';
    $html .='</select>';

    echo $html;

}
```

I dont know what name to use , how to retrieve it once is saved and how to display it in front for all widgets.

I just need to add simple select to display list of additional widget styles. and I would like to do this trough theme functions.php rather than creating a full blown plugin.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [How to store widget fields data as an array?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94625/73) contains a minimal yet complete example. You just have to change the form element.

Comment: @toscho I saw that but that is a plugin , I just need to add simple select to display list of additional widget styles. and I would like to do this trough theme functions.php rather than creating a full blown plugin.

Comment: Then just use the code in a theme without plugin headers. What is stopping you?

Comment: a humble I dont know how to.

Comment: @toscho , just tested your plugin , that is not it , I need to add select to all available widgets , not make widget with addable fields