# Meta Box Data added to header redirect

Tags: custom-field, metabox, forms

I got a lot of my code from this post: [Create more Meta Boxes as needed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/create-more-meta-boxes-as-needed)

What I need to happen is the user input a code and it redirects them to a specific url. I know I'm grabbing the data correctly as I was able to output it a list, but I can't figure out how to get it to function as the redirect. Here is the code:

```
        <?php 
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'dynamic_add_custom_box' );

//Do something with the data entered
add_action( 'save_post', 'dynamic_save_postdata' );

//Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens
function dynamic_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'dynamic_sectionid',
        __( 'My Codes', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'dynamic_inner_custom_box',
        'page');
}

//Prints the box content
function dynamic_inner_custom_box() {
    global $post;
    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'dynamicMeta_noncename' );
    ?>
    <div id="meta_inner">
    <?php

    //get the saved meta as an arry
    $all_codes = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'all_codes', true );
        $c = 0;
        if ( count( $all_codes ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( (array)$all_codes as $track ) {
                if ( isset( $track['code'] ) || isset( $track['url'] ) ) {
                    printf( '<p>Promo Code <input type="text" name="all_code[%1$s][code]" value="%2$s" /> -- URL : <input type="text" name="all_code[%1$s][url]" value="%3$s" /><span class="remove">%4$s</span></p>', $c, $track['code'], $track['url'], __( 'Remove Code' ) );
                    $c++;
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
<span id="here"></span>
<span class="add"><?php _e('Add Code'); ?></span>
<script>
    var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var count = <?php echo $c; ?>;
        $(".add").click(function() {
            count = count + 1;

            $('#here').append('<p> Promo Code <input type="text" name="all_codes['+count+'][code]" value="" /> -- URL : <input type="text" name="all_codes['+count+'][url]" value="" /><span class="remove">Remove Code</span></p>' );
            return false;
        });
        $(".remove").live('click', function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
    </script>
</div><?php

}

//When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function dynamic_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
    // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times
    if ( !isset( $_POST['dynamicMeta_noncename'] ) )
        return;

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['dynamicMeta_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

    $all_codes = $_POST['all_codes'];

    update_post_meta($post_id,'all_codes',$all_codes);
}
?>
```

And I'm trying to use this to make the redirect happen. But something isn't connecting since when you enter the code, nothing happens.

```
            <form action="" method="post">
        <p>enter your promo code:</p>
        <input type="text" name="all_codes" id="all_codes" />
        <input type="reset" id="all_codes" style="display:none"/>
        <script>$('#track').click();</script>
        <input type="submit" /> 


<?php 
    # Gets the array of CODE/URL pairs
    $all_codes = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'all_codes', true );
    # Get the URL correspondent to the posted 'codes'
    $redirect = $all_codes[ $_POST['url'] ];
    # Do the redirect
    header("Location: $redirect");
?>

</form>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? also note that [you can't send headers after content has been sent to the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php).

Comment: My original thought was using the switch statement like: `switch($_POST['codes']) {
        case "1234":
             header("Location: http://www.myfoursquare.net/archives");
            break;` ---which worked properly.
And this is the error when i turned on debugging: Undefined index: url   So obviously an issue.

Comment: The problem is that already pointed out by @Milo; you can't send headers after the page has started rendering. You need to process the redirect when the form is submitted and not at the tail end of the HTML form itself.