# Collection of fields in a single post

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, admin, advanced-custom-fields, admin-ui

It's possible to create custom post types and custom fields but, is it possible to create custom field collections?

That is, groups of different fields as an entity (a dropdown, two images and a textfield)?

https://drupal.org/project/field_collection

In Drupal there's something like this:
https://drupal.org/project/field_collection

Screenshot:
http://www.commonplaces.com/sites/commonplaces.com/files/images/blog/example-field-collection.png

And I was wondering what's the closest thing in WP.

Comment: Looks like a couple of meta boxes to me. What makes a set of fields a "collection"?

Comment: Those meta boxes could be a variable amount of images or any other kind of field. Hence why is not just meta boxes. At least that's what I think.

Comment: ummm... meta boxes can be (and basically are) "images or any other kind of field".

Comment: But don't you have to predefine how many of them you have?

Answer (score 0):

The closest Thing in WordPress would be a custom meta box with repeatable fields.
So to do that you would need create a a metabox using [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and if you look at this link you will also see an example of saving the custom fields in your meta box.

[here is an example on a related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/create-more-meta-boxes-as-needed/19852#19852) or if you want a much better option is to use a [ready made class](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/how-i-add-a-wordpress-metabox) which will let you do just that with a few OOP settings.