# printf - problem to understand code

Tags: plugins, php

I've recently build a plugin and used the code from this post right here: [Create more Meta Boxes as needed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/create-more-meta-boxes-as-needed)

The Code works fine, but I dont understand the last parameter in the printf section.

```
if ( isset( $track['title'] ) || isset( $track['track'] ) ) {
            printf( '<p>Song Title <input type="text" name="songs[%1$s][title]" value="%2$s" /> -- Track number : <input type="text" name="songs[%1$s][track]" value="%3$s" /><span class="remove">%4$s</span></p>', $c, $track['title'], $track['track'], __( 'Remove Track' ) );
            $c = $c +1;
        }
```

I dont get the last part, which is saying `__( 'Remove Track' )` could anyone explain this to me in detail?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__( 'Remove Track' )` is a translatable string. `__()`, `_e()`, `_x()`, ... all of them are gettext functions used by WordPress for language localization. It is missing the second parameter (optional), which is the textdomain, usually it should be:

```
__( 'Remove Track', 'your-plugin-text-domain' )
```

In that way, the string can be translated by your plugin without any conflict if the same string exists also in another plugin or in core.

You can get more details in [I18n for WordPress Developers](/https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Now things are clearer to me!